# How to change the inherited F-curve independently from the original one ?

Tags: keyframes, graph-editor

[image]

**what I did:**

I created a hammer, inserted two keyframes to rotate it a bit, set the curve to linear and extrapolated it linearly. Than I duplicated the hammer, the result was two hammers that spins synchronous.

**What I want to achieve:**

I would like the second hammer to spin with only half the speed or I would like to create a few hammers and each one spins some degrees ahead of the other. But I only have one curve in the graph editor for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try to use F-Curve-Modifiers. To do so:

1. Go to frame `0` and add a keyframe on the rotation Axes you want
2. In the Graph Editor bring up that sidebar by pressing <kbd>N</kbd>. Add a *Modifier > Generator*. This will give you the polinominal tools to create a Graph as in `y=mx+b` as you might remember from school.

   [image]
3. This value controls the ascent of the curve. By default it's `1`, so we have `y=0+1x`, so `y=x` meaning that for each 1 frame (one unit on the x axis), the curve ascends 1 unit on the y axis as well (it actually goes up to `57,296` because `1 rad= 57,296°`).

   [image]

So if you want to have a second object that rotates half of that speed, you just enter half of the value you entered at (3), `0.5` in my example.

Comment: a real eye opener

Comment: Hi blackdot, if you're interested in the key markup for future answers, here is the meta: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/524/what-case-should-letters-inside-kbd-tags-be

Answer (score 1):

Use the NLA editor

The Pushdown (double down arrow [insert icon] in the action or NLA editor moves the action to the NLA.

Changing the speed of an animation is described in [controlling speed of an action by driver or scripting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38558/controlling-speed-of-an-action-by-driver-or-scripting/38570#38570)

Move the action strip to offset the start time.