# How to make a F-curve with a constant and linear part?

Tags: python, bezier-curves, graph-editor, mathematics

[image]

As part of a problem I need to obtain a curve in the graph editor, that has a constant part , followed by a linear one.

for instance:

> for the interval [0,100] the curve is y=0
>
> for the interval [100,end] the curve is y=x-100

I tried under Add-Modifier>Generator,
but the closest curve I found was only a y=mx+n curve. 
There is also the option of using python to shape the curve,
but I do not know how.
I assumed, that maybe it could be possible to draw the curve by hand, but it does not seem so.

**How would you make a F-curve that looks like the white one in the picture ?**

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few ways I can think of.

3 Keyframes, linear interpolation.

Simple driver expression   `frame if (frame > 100) else 0`

Or if you are using modifiers, add two generators and restrict the frame range
0 + 0x for frames 0 to 100
-100 + 1x for frames 100 to

[image: Restricted Frame Range]

Also, as suggested here [How to change the inherited F-curve independently from the original one ?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38714/how-to-change-the-inherited-f-curve-independently-from-the-original-one) 
,  I recommend you look at the NLA editor, especially for offsetting the start of actions.

Comment: what is a driver ?

Comment: https://www.blender.org/manual/animation/basics/drivers.html