# Blender Graph editor Continuos animation

Tags: animation, graph-editor

How can we get a continuous progress(nonstop) rather than a cycle, for example, one has to move from one point to another[image].

Comment: Read this post for a step by step description on how to do this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38764/1853

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38767/how-to-make-a-f-curve-with-a-constant-and-linear-part

Answer (score 1):

To create a continuous line (rather than between two points) you can add an F-curve Modifier - see https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/modifiers.html

The Generator modifier allows you define the relationship between X and Y to generate the required graph. In your case you want polynomial order of 1 so it is of the form `y = mx + c` - ie, a straight line with the gradient `m` and cutting through the y-axis at `c`.