# Time remapping of a single action

Tags: animation, keyframes, timeline

I have two questions:

1) I need to time remap one single action (from 24 f/s to 8). Is there any way I can do it without time remapping the entire scene (which is already set to 8 f/s)?

2) I noticed that when I do the time remapping of an already animated scene, it doesn't affect the timeline's display. What's annoying about this is that key-framing is almost impossible. Is there any way to change timeline's display?

Comment: For part (i) have a look at http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38558/controlling-speed-of-an-action-by-driver-or-scripting/38570#38570

Comment: you could scale the keyframes in the graph editor or the dopes sheet